# Retirar NA em um Data Frame

Tags: r

Importo arquivo contendo mais de 30 colunas. Algumas linhas em branco que importei o R reconhece como "NA". Ao exportar estas mesmas colunas, as linhas que deveriam estar em branco (vazias) aparecem com "NA". Como faço para exportar trocando o "NA" por vazio? Não quero excluir o dado, apenas que ele apareça vazio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supondo que o conjunto de dados se chama `dados`, rode o seguinte comando:

```
write.csv(dados, file="NomeDoArquivo.csv", na=" ", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

em que

- `na=" "` diz que todo `NA` em `dados` será substituído por um espaço em branco
- `row.names=FALSE` informa o `R` pra não colocar o nome das linhas no csv final
- `quote=FALSE` tira as aspas dos nomes das colunas e das variáveis categóricas

Answer (score 5):

Nas funções `write.table`. `write.csv` e `write.csv2`, existe uma opção (`na`) onde você define como quer que sejam exportados os dados faltantes.

Tente `write.table(x, ..., na = "")`